Как получить сообщение от сервера, и снова отправить данные?
сервер
import { Server } from "socket.io";
const io = new Server({maxHttpBufferSize: 100e6});
io.on('connection', socket => {
console.log('user connected')
    socket.on('mess', async (coins) => {
        try {
            console.log(coins.length)
            
            } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message)
        }
    })
})

io.listen(3000);
console.log('Server is running!')

клиент
let coins = []
async function onMessage(e) {
    let data = JSON.parse(e.toString())
        //console.log(data)
        if (data.channel === "spot.pong"){
            console.log("Pong GATE")
        }
        let coin = {
            "exchange": "GATE",
            "symbol": data?.result?.s?.split('_').join(''),
            "time": data?.result?.t,
            "bids": data?.result?.bids,
            "asks": data?.result?.asks,
        }

        if (coin.symbol !== undefined){
            coins.push(coin)
        }
}
setInterval(async ()=>{
    console.log(coins.length)
    //console.log(formatBytes(sizeOf(coins)))
    gate.emit('mess', coins)
    coins = []
    console.log(coins.length)
}, 15000)

каждые 15 сек отправляю на сервер массив, но сервер не успевает принять его, и отправляется уже следующий. Как сделать, чтобы клиент дождался ответа от сервера, что массив принят и клиент отправлял новый массив?

так есть же метод socket.onmessage' который, как я понимаю, получает ответ от сервера. Собственно при получении надо отправлять новые данные......

и текущий подход с setInterval совершенно бессмысленный. раз есть сокет соединение, то есть постоянное открытое соединение с другой стороной, то что-то отправлять по интервалу - совершенно бессмысленно

на клиенте же есть работа с сокетами - ею и надо пользоваться  https://learn.javascript.ru/websockets

спасибо! сделал, один момент а как, первый ответ вернуть с сервера, чтобы клиент начал отправлять данные. он то отправляет, но пока массив пустой, в консоль нули приходят

клиент
gate.on('otvet', (data)=>{
if (data === 'received'){
console.log(coins.length)
gate.emit('mess', coins)
coins = []
}
})
сервер
io.on('connection', socket => {
socket.on('mess', async (coins) => {
try {
console.log(coins.length)
socket.emit('otvet', 'received')
} catch (e) {
console.log(e.message)
}
})
})

У сокета есть событие onconnect, вот там и надо реализовывать первую отправку сообщения
